Why do I need to model a join table class?
I have two classes in C#:
public class Student
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Email {get; set;}
    public List<Course> Courses {get; set;}
}

public class Course
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Desc {get; set;}
    public string MaxStudents {get; set;}
    public List<Student> Students {get; set;}
}

In the database, I have an additional table StudentCourse because of the many-to-many relationship. This table has one additional field in addition to the Id corresponding to the Student and Course table. Do I need to model the StudentCourse class? I use Dapper with SQL so I can check if the Student is enrolled for the course without additional class, same for enrolling or disenrolling. Is there a case where that class is needed?
The API works with both of the concepts, but which one is the more proper way to do this?

You say it has one other column other than the links off to the primary tables, so how are you planning to change the value of the one other column?

@flackoverstow By using SQL query updating that specifing column. But that was column with bool type so changing it is quite easy. Now I realise that if I have more complicated set of columns it's not that simple I may need a seperate model for that

In the majority of cases, a many-to-many intersection between two entities like Student and Course will turn out to be an entity in its own right... in this case, you have StudentCourse, but since we're talking about a full entity you might also give it a real name, like Enrollment.
These entities will further tend to have additional fields of their own. You've already admitted one column, but for an Enrollment it could also be things like FinalGrade, CreditHours, CreditType (audit, credit by exam, transfer, pass/fail, etc), DateRegistered, BillingStatus, etc.
Since we now have a full entity, of course this also includes a class definition in your C#.
If I were further defining this system, I would separate out a course definition from an instance of the course. A school might have a course offering like CS101: Introduction to Computer Science, and then have multiple sections taught for any given term. So you would want tables for Course and Section, where the Section table is responsible for storing things like who the instructor is for this instance, what term it's in, the time and room where it meets, etc, but the Course record still has the title, description, degree plan information (division, department, etc) and other things that don't change from instance to instance.
Therefore to map from a Student to their Course records we'd have an Enrollment table to hold keys for both the Student and the Section, and the Section table in turn holds keys for the Course. This is two separate JOINs (in the same query) in SQL, but you'll learn this is common and nothing out of the ordinary.

That makes sense. The Enrollment table may grow in future so this evolve in need of that kind of entity.

What is "admintted"?

@Enigmativity it's when someone wishing to enrol on a course has had all their paperwork sorted out ;)

@flackoverstow - Oh, "admitted". Obvious now.

It's good to use junction table for M-M relationship, StudenCourse in your case. It's because of normalization(avoids redundancy). This table has reference ids of both tables' records, normally.

Ok, the join table in DB is good option, but my question is about class based on that table.

I tend to make a class for them anyway, rather than try and work with them as M:M in C#
